# Grid on top of image with editing ability

Tags: c#, .net, graphics

I'm hoping someone can give me some guidance here.  I have been gogleing for a while now and I can't come up with anything that suits my needs.  I'm a bit of a programmer but not a pro and I have no graphics experience.  I am trying to develop a program for my wife to more easily transfer images to her needlepoint drawings.  I want to write a C# application that will let me load an image of almost any type and overlay a "grid" on top of it.  I want to also be able to implement simple "paint" operations like change the color of a grid square, color selector from the base image, bucket fill, etc.  Any suggestions and examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: I think you're better off using photoshop and loading a vector image of a grid as a new layer on top of your image.

Comment: Thanks but that is not an answer to my question.  It is easy to superimpose a grid on top of the image but I need to be able to edit the "top" layer where the grid resides.

Comment: I don't see the problem - you COULD edit it and perform the things you specified. I could tell you how to go about doing this in C#, it involves overriding the OnPaint method to paint whatever you want, using the Graphics class and drawing shapes with the predefined C# classes (Rectangle, Circle, etc)

Comment: andypopa- I apologize for reacting so negatively, like I said, I am not a graphics person and I do not own photoshop but I do have GIMP and Paint.NET.  I would appreciate any advise you can give me.

Comment: None taken man :D How would this grid look like? Add more details so I can come up with a good answer.

Comment: So here is what I am thinking.  I load an image into a picturebox but it is scaled down, like a thumbnail.  There will be a parameter to define the media, which in this case will be the grid height and width.  Then the user will click a "process" button and here is where I need help...  The "process" button will need to scan the source image and display it full size in another picturebox, this time inside a grid where all the grid cells are editable, by editable I mean you can change colors.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I still can't understand the nature of the grid. How many cells does it have? Is it a variable number? I suggest you try implementing your idea and asking questions along the way, whenever you reach a standstill.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented something similar for my wife. My basic approach:

1) Scale the image down to the number of necessary pixels. For example, if she's stitching the image on a 10x10 13-mesh canvas, that equates to an image of 130x130 pixels.

Here's some example code to start you off:

```
// use NearestNeighbor algorithm
public static unsafe Bitmap Reduce(Bitmap source, SizeF toSize, int threadCount)
{
    Bitmap reduced = new Bitmap((int)(toSize.Width * threadCount), (int)(toSize.Height * threadCount));
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(reduced))
    {
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        g.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, reduced.Size));
    }
    return reduced;
}
```

2) Display the pixelated image full screen. This will provide a grid-like effect.

3) Display a color palette from DMC's yarn code card, or taken from the image (after down-scaling). Then have the mouse cursor pick up a color by clicking on it, then applying it to the cell that it was subsequently clicked on.

Here's some code for picking up the mouse cursor:

```
public Point GetPicturePointAtClick()
{
    Point p = Cursor.Position;
    Point picturePoint = previewBox.PointToClient(p);

    if (Zoom != 0)
    {
        picturePoint.X = (int)(picturePoint.X / Zoom);
        picturePoint.Y = (int)(picturePoint.Y / Zoom);
    }
    return picturePoint;
}
```

The idea here is to map the clicked area to the correct pixel in the reduced image, math:

```
Point reducedPoint = 
    new Point(
        (int)(picPoint.X * (_reduced.Width / (float)WorkingBitmap.Width)), 
        (int)(picPoint.Y * (_reduced.Height / (float)WorkingBitmap.Height)));
```

There's a lot of code ahead of you. Did you try an online custom needlepoint provider? Try one of these sites, they're both pretty good and customization is free:
http://www.needlepaint.com/
http://www.pepitaneedlepoint.com/